# dynamic postgres inside shell script not working

Tags: postgresql, psql, dynamic-sql, scripting

```
PG_CMD="psql -d portal -U portal -c "
PG_CMD_TP="psql -d portal -U portal -t -P format=unaligned -c "
abc()
{
 $PG_CMD " 
        DO \$$

           BEGIN
                   select * from customer;
          END; 
        \$$";
}
*******MAIN***
abc
```

I want to print result of query on command line as well as I want to send it to excel file.

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Three misunderstandings:

1. You cannot return data from a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) command.
2. You cannot [`SELECT` without target](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) in plpgsql code. That's what the error message tells you.
3. You don't need either for a simple `SELECT` statement. Just run the statement itself:

```
abc()
{
 $PG_CMD 'select * from customer'
}
```

Comment: thanks Erwin just one more question I need to use variable value inside copy function while writing in .csv format

Comment: @user3526905: That's seems like an unrelated question. Please start a new question, comments are not the place. Or consider related question on SO like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601349/postgres-function-from-newbee/10603581#10603581) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019508/copy-with-dynamic-file-name/16021835#16021835).